# RSA Encryption Java, Key Exchange

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

Trying to Encrypt a text message using RSA algorithm. To encrypt the message the key from client is required. How are the keys exchanged. I have studied few key exchange algorithms but could not find any example code.

Can some one guide to a tutorial, on how to exchange the keys on internet.

Comment: So in you scenario, do you have the public key/cert for the recipient? Does each party have this?

Comment: Not a programming specific question, so this is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use this sample [program](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.security.component.doc/security-component/JceDocs/api_sampleprograms.html) for key exchange algorithm. Its a Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange between 2 Parties. Just try to understand what this algo is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

Comment: Diffie-Hellman is pretty much what everyone uses, you need to transmit the key "out of band" but that is often not practical. Diffie-hellman allows two parties to agree on a key for encryption without ever actually transmitting said key. My mathematician friend said it was mathemagic when I demonstrated it to them.

Comment: Diffie-Hellman is not useful when encryption with an RSA key pair is required, as it does not provide authentication. It does help against eavesdropping, but most of the time it is possible to have a man in the middle. For just eavesdropping, you might as well exchange public keys in plain, and then encrypt with the public keys at the other side, so you would not need Diffie-Hellman anymore.

Comment: @feldoh it is pretty much magic when you first see it, but it is not something that can solve authentication issues. You need some sort of trust to exist beforehand. In the case of RSA, you don't need DH anymore, although it can be used to establish sessions. See my comment above this one.

Comment: Thats very true, it is usually only used to start a secure session to allow more secure authentication, it is not authentication in its own right in part because it is vulnerable to man in the middle attacks. But most SSH software still uses it for session initialisation in my experience.

Comment: @feldoh it certainly can be part of the protocol, but just specifying DH as the solution is certainly not correct.

Comment: Fair enough, I would agree with that, I perhaps phrased poorly.

Comment: The link is dead but I think this is now the correct location: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.70.doc/security-component/JceDocs/api_sampleprograms.html

Answer (score 0):

The main methods of distributing keys are through e.g. PGP, which uses signatures from other trusted parties to confer trust in keys. X509 certificates, such as used in browsers, use certificate chains, where a certificate from a higher up authority is explicitly trusted. These methods of trusting certificates is called PKI, public key infrastructure.

If you don't have an established trust you might send each other a certificate or public key, by mail then calculate a "fingerprint" over the certificate. Then use an out of band procedure (telephone, envelope etc.) to validate the fingerprint. Or simply meet up and exchange a USB thumb drive after checking each others credentials.